# How do I bind the Header of a Datagrid to a value in a viewmodel?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagrid

I'm trying to bind a string from my viewmodel to the header of a DataGrid. Below is my .xaml code:

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource CustomDataGridStyle}" ItemsSource="{Binding InputDataCollection}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="{Binding InputNameHeader}" Binding="{Binding Name}" Width="50*"
                                ElementStyle="{StaticResource CellTextStyleR}" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource HeaderRight}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="{Binding InputStateHeader}" Binding="{Binding State}" Width="50*"
                                ElementStyle="{StaticResource CellTextStyleL}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

The problem I'm running into is that the column headers are always blank. I assume it's because I defined the ItemSource and that the things I'm binding the headers to is not part of that ItemSource.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can define the Headers with strings from the viewmodel in this situation?

Comment: Is your Datacontext correct?  What binding errors are you getting, if any?
How are InputNameHeader and InputStateHeader defined, in the viewmodel? :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Figured it out.

I had to move the Header binding to the DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate and use RelativeSource. Now it works as it should.

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource CustomDataGridStyle}" ItemsSource="{Binding InputDataCollection}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" Width="50*" ElementStyle="{StaticResource CellTextStyleR}" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource HeaderRight}">
                <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding DataContext.InputNameHeader, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Input State" Binding="{Binding State}" Width="50*" ElementStyle="{StaticResource CellTextStyleL}">
                <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding DataContext.InputStateHeader, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to bind the `HeaderText` property to properties in the view model. It's only the values displayed in the columns that are bound to the data source.

As long as `InputNameHeader` and `InputStateHeader` have been defined in your view model, you've implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged` and you've set the `DataContext` of the view to the view model it should (famous last words) just work.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that you have not defined `InputNameHeader` and `InputStateHeader` as properties, in the viewmodel.  If they are not properties, then they cannot be bound to, and you'll get no value (along with binding errors.)

I was able to get a quick test of your setup working using the following, in my viewmodel:  (Keep in mind that I tossed this into a program that I'm working on, so it's using `BindableBase` and `SetProperty` from [Prism](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg406140.aspx)'s method of notifying.  Adapt to your program, as necessary, and my apologies.)

```
public class TestClass : BindableBase
{
  private string name;
  public string Name
  {
    get { return this.name; }
    set { SetProperty(ref this.name, value); }
  }

  private string state;
  public string State
  {
    get { return this.state; }
    set { SetProperty(ref this.state, value); }
  }
}

public class YourClass : BindableBase  
{
  public ObservableCollection<TestClass> InputDataCollection { get; set; }
  public string InputNameHeader { get; set;}
  public string InputStateHeader { get; set; }

  public YourClass()
  {
    // Test Data
    InputDataCollection = new ObservableCollection<TestClass>()
    {
      new TestClass() { Name = "Name1", State = "State1" },
      new TestClass() { Name = "Name2", State = "State2" }
    };
    InputNameHeader = "Name";
    InputStateHeader = "State";
  }
}
```

Comment: That is more or less what my viewmodel looks like. I am setting the InputNameHeader and InputStateHeader (and they're spelled correctly; triple-checked that again). Can you think of another reason that the string wouldn't make it to the view?

Comment: Not offhand.  Can you add your viewmodel and any binding errors, that appear in your output, to the original question?

Answer (score 0):

When Binding to properties that are not in your ItemsSource you'll need to specify your **ViewModel** as your your **Source**.

```
xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:My.App.ViewModels.Test"

<UserControl.Resources>
    <viewModels:YourClass x:Key="myViewModel"/>
</UserControl.Resources>

<DataGrid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource CustomDataGridStyle}" ItemsSource="{Binding InputDataCollection}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="{Binding InputNameHeader, Source={StaticResource myViewModel}}" Binding="{Binding Name}" Width="50*"
                                ElementStyle="{StaticResource CellTextStyleR}" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource HeaderRight}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="{Binding InputStateHeader, Source={StaticResource myViewModel}}" Binding="{Binding State}" Width="50*"
                                ElementStyle="{StaticResource CellTextStyleL}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: My viewmodel class has a constructor that requires a string, so I don't think this would work... Is there a way to use the DataContext?

Comment: You can use Element Binding.  If you set the DataContext on your UserControl, then you can use something like this:

`{Binding Path=DataContext.InputNameHeader, ElementName=UserControlName}`

Use the name of the control that has it's DataContext bound to the ViewModel